# Oracle Client installation

Tags: oracle, client-server

I need both 32 bit and 64 bit oracle client installations to be done on a single machine.

Can any tell me would it be possible to do so or are there any issues (that you anticipate or have encountered). Apologies if it is a repeated question.

Comment: When it is Just _Oracle client_, `32/64 bit` really matters? And I believe, we can always have both, but `ORACLE_HOME` is the one that finally will be referred! And you can always specify only one!

Comment: Database was configured remotely and so I need oracle client software to be installed on host machine. Along with that for reporting purpose I need oracle 32 bit client to be installed. So in this case, would just installing 32 bit works fine?